# Disable certain options in a drop down select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need to disable option "5" & "6" when the option value "2" is selected. It should display all the options in the List_2 when option "1" is selected.  How can I do that using jQuery or any other method.

```js
if ($('option[value=2]').prop('selected', true)) {
      $('option[value=5]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
```

```html
<HTML>
    <body>

      <select id= "List_1">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    
    </select>

    <select id= "List_2">
      <option value="4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="5">Option 5</option>
      <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    </select>

</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You can try a jQuery code at least, no one will write code for you
Here people will help you with the modifications and issues you're facing

Comment: @akbansa Not everyone is like you mate. I already got the answer thanks to the actual people who helped me out. Keep commenting !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With plain JS:

```js
document.getElementById('List_1').onchange = function() {

  document.getElementById('List_2')[1].disabled = (document.getElementById('List_1').selectedIndex == 1);
  document.getElementById('List_2')[2].disabled = (document.getElementById('List_1').selectedIndex == 1);
}
```

```html
<select id="List_1">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>

</select>

<select id="List_2">
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
  <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/eurbvzk1/

```js
var disabledDic = {
  "1" : ["6"],
  "2" : ["4", "5"],
  "3" : []
}

$('select#list_1').on('change', function(){
  $('select#list_2 option').each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
  });
  
 var disableOption = disabledDic[$(this).val()];
  $.each( disableOption, function(i){
    $('option[value="' + disableOption[i] + '"]').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list_1">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select id= "list_2">
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
  <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

Create a dictionary that will contain each first select option as key & value will be list of disabled options from second list.

Onchange method check the dictionary & loop through the disabled value.

Hope this will help you.